# Draw without anti-aliasing for single node in SceneKit

Tags: macos, scenekit

I'm doing some visualizations using SceneKit and the 'normal' objects draw just fine. I like the anti-aliasing to gain some apparent resolution.

I also want to draw a grid of lines using a custom geometry. Drawing it is no problem, but I'm having problems with the anti-aliasing, causing 2-pixel wide gray lines if the line happens to be between pixels.

If I disable anti-aliasing, the grid draws fine but the other objects get the well known staircase edges.

Is there a way to disable anti-aliasing for just a single node (hierarchy)?

I've tried using a SCNTechnique, with a draw pass defined as follows:

```
<key>draw</key>
<string>DRAW_NODE</string>
<key>node</key>
<string>grid</string>
<key>outputs</key>
<dict>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>COLOR</string>
</dict>
<key>inputs</key>
<dict/>
<key>colorStates</key>
<dict>
    <key>clear</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>samples</key>
<integer>1</integer>
```

I thought that setting the samples to 1 should disable the anti-aliasing for this pass.
This does draw the grid, but only some of the pixels:
[image: wrong grid]

Zooming and panning various the amount of pixels drawn, including none.

Am I going the right way? Or do I have to disable anti-aliasing for the whole view?

Comment: if you are having trouble with lines between 2 pixels, then round the position coordinates so that it is on one

Comment: The problem is that SceneKit does not provide any uniforms that allow me to nudge the coordinates in the vertex shader to pixels. If I recalculate the geometry for every camera move, I might as well do all drawing on the CPU.

Comment: @RemcoPoelstra You would do the rounding of position coordinates in the `.geometry` shader modifier (on the GPU, not the CPU).  Something like this: `vec4 mvpPosition = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform * _geometry.position; mvpPosition.xy = round(mvpPosition.xy / scn_node.inverseResolution) * scn_node.inverseResolution; _geometry.position = mvpPosition * scn_node.inverseViewProjectionTransform;` _(completely untested and should compute `vec2 resolution = vec2(1) / scn_node.inverseResolution;` upfront, but you get the gist)_.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Thanks for your comment. I ended up with using two SCNView's on top of each other.

Comment: @RemcoPoelstra Huh, yeah, I guess that would work.  _Inefficient, but hey, why not?_  Regarding my comment above— custom shader modifier code should actually be unnecessary as well.  You should've been able to accomplish this with “nearest” texture filtering mode (the default is “linear”) by setting the `SCNMaterial`'s `.diffuse.minificationFilter` & `.diffuse.magnificationFilter` to `.nearest`.  _I'd post a full answer, but then I'd need double-check my assumptions, and I'm a bit too busy right now with my current project to do that and a full write up. ;-)_